# pandas - json: parent sequence ID

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column of nested json objects I wouls like them to be normalised and they must also get a parent ID.
example data:

```
{"subscription":[{"subscription_boo":true,"subscription_ref_prefix":"S_","product":[{"no_of_products":1,"product_id":1,"product":[{"no_of_products":1,"product_id":1.1,"product":[{"no_of_products":1,"product_id":1.11}]},{"no_of_products":1,"product_id":1.2}]}]},{"subscription_boo":true,"subscription_ref_prefix":"B_","product":[{"no_of_products":1,"product_id":2,"product":[{"no_of_products":1,"product_id":2.1,"product":[{"no_of_products":1,"product_id":2.11,"product":[{"no_of_products":1,"product_id":2.11}]},{"no_of_products":1,"product_id":2.11}]},{"no_of_products":1,"product_id":2.2}]}]}]}
```

I now want to add product_seq stating the sequence of the product as well as the parent product sequence while normalizing this JSON.

desired output is:

```
subscription_boo subscription_ref_prefix no_of_products product_id product_seq parent_product_seq
    True    S_      1.0    1.00     1    0
    True    S_      1.0    1.10     2    1
    True    S_      1.0    1.20     3    1
    True    S_      1.0    1.11     4    2
    True    B_      1.0    2.00     5    0
    True    B_      1.0    2.10     6    5
    True    B_      1.0    2.20     7    5
    True    B_      1.0    2.11     8    6
    True    B_      1.0    2.11     9    6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your nested products are very intricated. I suggest to flatten them with a recursive function before using `json_normalize`:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

data = """{"subscription":[{"subscription_boo":true,"subscription_ref_prefix":"S_","product":[{"no_of_products":1,"product_id":1,"product":[{"no_of_products":1,"product_id":1.1,"product":[{"no_of_products":1,"product_id":1.11}]},{"no_of_products":1,"product_id":1.2}]}]},{"subscription_boo":true,"subscription_ref_prefix":"B_","product":[{"no_of_products":1,"product_id":2,"product":[{"no_of_products":1,"product_id":2.1,"product":[{"no_of_products":1,"product_id":2.11,"product":[{"no_of_products":1,"product_id":2.11}]},{"no_of_products":1,"product_id":2.11}]},{"no_of_products":1,"product_id":2.2}]}]}]}"""

input_rec = json.loads(data)["subscription"]

product_seq = 0
def flatten_products(prod_list):
    flattened_prod = []

    def flatten_product(prod_list, parent=0):
        global product_seq
        for prod in prod_list:
            product_seq +=1
            flattened_prod.append({
                "no_of_products": prod["no_of_products"],
                "product_id": prod["product_id"],
                "product_seq": product_seq,
                "parent_product_seq": parent
            })
            flatten_product(prod.get("product", []), product_seq)

    flatten_product(prod_list)  
    return flattened_prod

for sub in input_rec:
    sub["product"] = flatten_products(sub["product"])

df = pd.json_normalize(input_rec, record_path=["product"], meta=["subscription_boo", "subscription_ref_prefix"])
```

Output:

```
   no_of_products  product_id  product_seq  parent_product_seq subscription_boo subscription_ref_prefix
0               1        1.00            1                   0             True                      S_
1               1        1.10            2                   1             True                      S_
2               1        1.11            3                   2             True                      S_
3               1        1.20            4                   1             True                      S_
4               1        2.00            5                   0             True                      B_
5               1        2.10            6                   5             True                      B_
6               1        2.11            7                   6             True                      B_
7               1        2.11            8                   7             True                      B_
8               1        2.11            9                   6             True                      B_
9               1        2.20           10                   5             True                      B_
```